# Perl: Inheritance in modules - import and interfacing

Tags: perl, oop, inheritance, module

I am trying to create my own module in perl that provides functions for data analysis out of a database.
I have several functions in EDL::Functions, eg. EDL::Functions::Average.

```
package EDL::Functions;
use warnings;
use strict;
```

---

```
package EDL::Functions::Average;
use parent "EDL::Functions";
sub new{...}
sub execute {...}
```

1) What do i have to add so `use EDL::Functions;` automatically imports all modules in `EDL::Functions`? Currently i have to import all submodules (in `EDL::Functions`)in order to make it work:

```
BEGIN {
 our $VERSION = 5.20;
 use EDL::Functions::Average;
 use EDL::Functions::GetAllValues;
 use EDL::Functions::GetValueStart;
 use EDL::Functions::GetValueEnd;
 use EDL::Functions::Min;
 use EDL::Functions::Max;
 use EDL::Functions::Median;
}
```

**2) I want to make sure that if someone else builds his own function module the compilation will fail if it doesn't have the functions `new` and `execute`. How can i achieve that?**

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Are you using OOP? If not, are you using Exporter?

Comment: Then `use EDL::Functions` should make `EDL::Functions::Average->new` available.

Comment: it doesn't: "can't load package ...", i have the Functions.pm in a folder called EDL, and the functions in EDL/Functions. That's as it should be right?

Comment: Show the code. I can't reproduce the problem.

Comment: If you're having trouble locating your library files, you may want to `use lib ...` and perhaps `use FindBin;`

Comment: @tjd it does find EDL::Functions and EDL::Functions::* when i load them seperately. It does not recognize the submodules' methods after loading the parent module via use `EDL::Functions`

Answer (score 0):

It should work

```
 perl -I ./ -MEDL::Functions -e 'EDL::Functions::Average->new();'
```

returns "I'm new".

cat EDL/Functions.pm

```
package EDL::Functions;
use warnings;
use strict;


package EDL::Functions::Average;
use parent "EDL::Functions";
sub new{ print "I'm new"; }
sub execute { print "Executing something";}

1;
```

But I prefere different structure, not declare several packages in one pm file. It'll save time for other devs and follows common practice, so EDL::Functions::Average should be at EDL/Functions/Average.pm

Comment: I've split it, however i still can't access the submodules via `use EDL::Functions`. Which seems weird to me.

Comment: Using 'use modules' is useless or I missed part of realization, they are already in the same scope. What error you got when you try to access it?

Comment: Can't locate object method "new" via package "EDL::Functions::Average" (perhaps you forgot to load "EDL::Functions::Average"?) at "the path where the calling module is, not the Functions module". Which is obviously what causes the Can't locate error. But what makes perl oversee that it is part of the EDL::Functions module?

Comment: Strange, could you verify that my code works on your box?
Then paste your code and tell how you run it.

Comment: your code returns nothing on my box. When i write a short perl file, it does exactly what it should do. Even without the -I. When i split the file again the same error as before occurs.

Comment: perl -v and perl -V please

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75804/discussion-between-flo-win-and-neonox-neonox).